# SQLANYWHERE10 PHP Module

Tags: apache-2.2, php, sqlanywhere

I added the extension to php.ini to get the module to load but now I am getting this error

Warning: sasql_connect() [function.sasql-connect]: The SQLAnywhere client libraries could not be loaded. Please ensure that libdbcapi.so can be found in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable

Any ideas?

Centos 5.7 64-bit
PHP 5.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is updated to point to the SQLAnywhere lib directory.

You can append to your current `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by doing the following;

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/directory/here
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Where do I do that?